# Remove all other trailing whitespace characters except tab in Java

Tags: java

I know that removing whitespaces is as easy as String.trim(). But my string contains tab (\t) characters which I would like to keep.

Example:

```
"teststring\t\t\t     ".trimSpaceNotTab() => "teststring\t\t\t"
```

My current implementation is to use split();

```
String[] arr = tabbedString.split("\t");
```

Then joining them somewhere as a string.

I find this implementation slow and ugly.

Is there a better way in Java where I can retain the tabs?

Comment: It would be nice if you add an example input and output string in your question.

Comment: Err, a tab *is* whitespace, by all definitions I have ever seen. So are space, \f, \r, \n.

Comment: @EJP, exactly! But in this case, I would like to keep the tabs.

Comment: are you looking for a way to trim off whitespace from beginning/end, but leave trailing leading tabs? ie. `"  \t hello \t  "` => `"\t hello \t"`?

Comment: Do you want feature similar to `trim()` (but leaves tabs), or do you just want to remove all white spaces (except tabs)?

Comment: @nmenego - EJP's point is that you are not expressing yourself clearly.  Your question **read literally** says that TABs should be removed and not removed ... and that is obviously nonsense.  There is also the problem that you don't say **which** non-TAB whitespace you want removed.  All of it / them, or only those at the beginning and end of a String?  And what about spaces between (say) the end of the last word and a following TAB?

Comment: @StephenC thanks for pointing that out. I changed the title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
tabbedString.replaceAll("[ \n\x0B\f\r]","")
```

Function used - [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

In case you'd like to also go for tabs and remove them, use a predefined character class `\s`

[Pattern Summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Comment: I am trying this but Eclipse says "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Answer (score 0):

Go through the string and ask each Char if its whitespace using the [isSpaceChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29)

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that replace all white space but not tab(\t).